# React Native Sort Data by CreatedAt?

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-ios

**I have Problem is don't sort data by Date**

**this is my output**

```
[ { text: '3',
    id: '1',
    device: 'I',
    name: 'Vishal',
    createdAt: '2018-12-03T11:10:19.287Z' },
  { text: '1',
    id: '1',
    device: 'I',
    name: 'Vishal',
    createdAt: '2018-12-03T11:02:14.621Z' },
  { text: '2',
    id: '2',
    device: 'A',
    name: 'Vishal',
    createdAt: '2018-12-03T11:02:20.669Z' } ]
```

**Actual Output is here...**

```
[ { text: '1',
    id: '1',
    device: 'I',
    name: 'Vishal',
    createdAt: '2018-12-03T11:02:14.621Z' },
  { text: '2',
    id: '2',
    device: 'A',
    name: 'Vishal',
    createdAt: '2018-12-03T11:02:20.669Z' },
    { text: '3',
    id: '1',
    device: 'I',
    name: 'Vishal',
    createdAt: '2018-12-03T11:10:19.287Z' } ]
```

Comment: Your question got closed as being unclear. To improve the changes that someone can help, add the minimal code that reproduces the problem. For more on this, see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add This Lib**

```
"underscore": "^1.9.1"

import _ from 'underscore';
let temp = _.sortBy(items, 'createdAt');
console.log('Results....',temp);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[ { text: '1',
    id: '1',
    device: 'I',
    name: 'Vishal',
    createdAt: '2018-12-03T11:02:14.621Z' },
  { text: '2',
    id: '2',
    device: 'A',
    name: 'Vishal',
    createdAt: '2018-12-03T11:02:20.669Z' },
    { text: '3',
    id: '1',
    device: 'I',
    name: 'Vishal',
    createdAt: '2018-12-03T11:10:19.287Z' } ]
```